# Finding the longest chain of array element indices and values

Tags: javascript

I can't solve a problem.
We have an array. If we take a value, the index of it means port ID, and the value itself means the other port ID it is connected to. Need to find the start index of the longest sequential connection to element which value is -1.

I made a graphic explanation to describe the case for the array [2, 2, 1, 5, 3, -1, 4, 5, 2, 3]. On image the longest connection is purple (3 segments).

[image: graphic description]

I need to make a solution by a function `getResult(connections)` with a single argument. I don't know how to do it, so i decided to return another function with several arguments which allows me to make a recursive solution.

```js
function getResult(connections) {
  return f(connections.findIndex(e => e === -1), connections, 0, []);
}

function f(index, cnx, counter, branches) {
  counter++;  
  for (let i = 0; i < cnx.length; i++) {
    if (cnx[i] === index) {
      branches.push([i, counter]);
      return f(i, cnx, counter, branches);
    }
  }
  return branches.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])[0][0];
}

console.log(getResult([1, 2, -1])); // expected 0
console.log(getResult([1, -1, 1, 2])); // expected 3
console.log(getResult([2, 1, -1])); // expected 0
console.log(getResult([3, 4, 1, -1, 3])); // expected 2
console.log(getResult([1, 0, -1, 2])); // expected 3
console.log(getResult([3, 2, 1, -1])); // expected 0
console.log(getResult([2, 2, 1, 5, 3, -1, 4, 5, 2, 3])); // expected 6
```

Anyway, the code doesn't work completely properly.
Would you please explain my mistakes?
Is it possible to solve the problem by a function with just one original argument?

Comment: @DBS It's a graph representation, and they want to find the longest path

Comment: You probably don't want to `return` immediately after doing any recursive call - you only want to return from the function after sorting the array

Comment: Otherwise your approach looks good. I would however suggest to simplify the call to `f(-1, connections, 0, []);` (instead of using `findIndex`), and to put the `branches.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])[0][0]` statement inside the `getResult` function (with a `const branches = [];`) so that you don't sort the array at each recursive step.

Comment: "*Is it possible to solve the problem by a function with just one original argument?*" - you did, and you did well. Using helper functions is standard practice. If you don't want to create an extra global variable, you can even declare your helper function *inside* `getResult`.

Comment: In your Question you say `[2, 2, 1, 5, 3, -1, 4, 5, 2, 3]` should have the longest path of 3, but in the code you say `// expected 6` which one is true?

Comment: @Raqha we have to find the start index of the longest path. 6 is a right answer for the path of 3 connections

Comment: @toyboy oh sorry, my bad. overflew that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The code doesn't work completely properly. Would you please explain my mistakes?

You were quite close. The main problem is that the `return` keyword in front of the recursive calls terminates the `for` loop and the entire `f` function prematurely. This will cause it to visit only the nodes on the first possible branch, not all of them.

The other issue is that `branches` might be empty at the end of the function, yet you still access `[0][0]`. Instead return the entire array from `f`, and access the first tuple on in `getResult`.

These two small fixes already make the function work<sup>1</sup>:

```js
function getResult(connections) {
  return f(connections.findIndex(e => e === -1), connections, 0, [])[0][0];
}

function f(index, cnx, counter, branches) {
  counter++;  
  for (let i = 0; i < cnx.length; i++) {
    if (cnx[i] === index) {
      branches.push([i, counter]);
      f(i, cnx, counter, branches);
    }
  }
  return branches.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
}

console.log(getResult([1, 2, -1])); // expected 0
console.log(getResult([1, -1, 1, 2])); // expected 3
console.log(getResult([2, 1, -1])); // expected 0
console.log(getResult([3, 4, 1, -1, 3])); // expected 2
console.log(getResult([1, 0, -1, 2])); // expected 3
console.log(getResult([3, 2, 1, -1])); // expected 0
console.log(getResult([2, 2, 1, 5, 3, -1, 4, 5, 2, 3])); // expected 6
```

<sub>1: Actually, there's an edge case where it still doesn't work: when called on the empty array as `getResult([])`, it shouldn't throw an exception if `branches` is empty. This can be fixed by an specifically handling that case with an `if` condition, or by including the tuple `[-1, 0]` (no node, distance 0) in the `branches`.</sub>

Additional improvements would be to do also the sorting only once at the end in `getResult`, and starting the search directly with `f(-1, connections, 0, []);` instead of using `findIndex`.

> Is it possible to solve the problem by a function with just one original argument? I don't know how to do it, so i decided to return another function with several arguments which allows me to make a recursive solution.

Introducing a helper function is a totally appropriate solution, this approach is good!

While it's always possible to write a recursive scheme as a loop with an explicit stack, that is usually unwieldy and incomprehensible. With the [DFS approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) you chose, a recursive function is the easiest and cleanest way to write it.

If you don't want to create an extra global variable, you can even declare your helper function inside `getResult`. This also allows accessing the `connections` directly from the upper scope, instead of passing it in as a function parameter. The same can be done to the `branches` variable:

```js
function getResult(connections) {
  const branches = [];
  function f(index, distance) {
    branches.push([index, distance]);
    for (let i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
      if (connections[i] === index) {
        f(i, distance+1);
      }
    }
  }
  f(-1, 0);
  branches.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
  return branches[0][0];
}

console.log(getResult([1, 2, -1])); // expected 0
console.log(getResult([1, -1, 1, 2])); // expected 3
console.log(getResult([2, 1, -1])); // expected 0
console.log(getResult([3, 4, 1, -1, 3])); // expected 2
console.log(getResult([1, 0, -1, 2])); // expected 3
console.log(getResult([3, 2, 1, -1])); // expected 0
console.log(getResult([2, 2, 1, 5, 3, -1, 4, 5, 2, 3])); // expected 6
```

As for further alternatives and optimisations:

- you could use an iterative [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) with a queue. Notice that although your input format generally is a graph, the connected component that you will traverse is guaranteed to be a tree rooted at `-1`, with each child node pointing to its parent, never forming a circle (since there is no node `-1` that points anywhere).
- instead of keeping around all "branches" (node indices with their distance) around in a list, keep only the one with the maximum distance you encountered so far.
- instead of repeatedly iterating the `connections` array to find children of a node (the `i`s referencing the current `index`), build an actual tree structure in a single iteration of the `connections`, then traverse that tree to find the deepest branch.

Comment: I appreciate your help, your detailed answer is very helpful 
Your improvements are so nice! I didn't think in that direction

As for graph traversing methods, I don't know the theory, I'll read about them, thanks. 
I never worked as a programmer, would you tell please, if graph traversing is a frequent task to solve in real life programming?

Comment: Depends on what you're doing as a programmer, but it does come up from time to time. And trees are very common.